# Are the words "meter, liter, period" partitives?

Tags: nouns

Some words of nouns are defined as partitives.(bottle, plate)

But "meter, liter, period" they are partitives?

Partitives are things which are in that size, right?

Can I say:

***The wine that I bought yesterday is one bottle!***

***The food that he ate is two plates.***

***The food that he ate is one bite.***

***The cloth is two meters.***

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe these would be considered partitives, but the more natural way to use them is:

> I bought one bottle of wine yesterday
>
> He ate two plates of food
>
> He ate one bite of food
>
> It is two meters of cloth

Your examples get the meaning across but they are not natural English.

Of course bottle, plate, meter, etc. are not *always* partitives but can be used on their own.

> He shot the bottle off of the fence
>
> The plate is on the table.
>
> The meter is the standard unit of metric distance.

Comment: But I have looked up many documents. None of them says "meter,liter“ are partitives...I don't know why. It makes me think, in some contexts, we can say" I want two bottles" "I want one more plate"(Like everybody knows what things you want). But can we say:"I want two hours" "I want two meters"?(They makes me think you want time, you want length, not things right?)

Comment: @moyeea As far as I can tell, these words *can* be partitives, but they aren't *only* partitives.  But as usual you're asking multiple questions in the comments which can get confusing to answer properly  :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!! But I think sometimes, we don't need to say everything, right? Like: We are tasting wines, can I say: One glass is ok./ I just want one glass.(everybody knows what I want)

Comment: Yes, just like other languages you can leave out *certain* words and everyone still knows what you mean.  "Anyone want some more (wine)?"  "I'll have another," "Just half for me," "We're out of red (wine)," "I'll have the white (wine) then," etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!!Just one concept that I'm not clear. a bottle, a bite, These quantifiers still refer to the things in reality right? Like a bottle, refers to the liquid which has the same amount of a bottle of XXX, am I right?not just number,right?

Comment: @moyeea That sounds more like a philosophical question than a linguistic question.  A bottle of wine could either refer to the bottle itself, or the amount of wine that would fit in a bottle.  A bite of food could either be the bite itself, or the amount of food that would fit in your mouth.  It's kind of both at the same time.